# Complete all Salesforce trailhead trails, modules and projects

Tags: trailhead

Is it possible to complete using only one dev org?

Comment: what do you mean? for trailhead you can use 1 or multiple org .. what is youe issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. New trails regarding "Wave" specifically require a special org.

Also, there is a trail about Authentication that strongly suggests you get a new one.

I'm curious, why do you need/want to do it with just one org? Developer orgs are free...

Comment: To accumulate all rewarded points in one place. If I log in from different dev org then all my progress will be flushed, right?

Comment: Nope, that is not correct. Always log in TO TRAILHEAD with the same creds (sorry for caps, wanted to emphasize). When you get to the "Exam" part, it asks you to log in to your Dev Org again. That's when you'd put the new creds. I;ve successfully done this.